# AKKA: Actor routers message persistence

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, akka, typesafe-stack

I'm writing a webspider and allocating it on Heroku and after the main actor (the one that allocates the router) reaches 512Mb it crashes.

Basically every URL parsed is sent to the FetchRouter. The list of messages of the queue is to big to get in memory.

Is there any way to store this list in the Disk ?

```
fetcherRouter = context.actorOf(Props[URLFetcher].withRouter(RandomRouter(30)), name = "fetcherRouter")
```

Comment: The problem is that one loaded page will generate multitude of new links to visit, so your mailbox will blow up. I don't know how crawlers handle this in general, but there should be a lot of research available about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed.

There is `FileBasedMailbox`. Look in section 7.1, "Durable Mailboxes," of the Akka 2.0.x PDF (or corresponding Web page).

Comment: Yes, but that does not save you from running out of memory, it just saves the messages.

Comment: Guys, I can't tell play2.1 to read the configuration to use a FileBasedMailbox for my router. Do you how to do it?